# How does the DBInputFormat work in case of MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database, hadoop

When running a map reduce program on a DB like MYSQL, I just wondered whether the query is fired on the database first and then the resultset is obtained and then the splits are created to be operated by the individual mappers each taking a split.

Comment: Why don't you ever accept any answers and ask lots of questions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it first retrieves all the records and then create the logical splits as you may see from the `setInput()`'s signature:

```
public static void setInput(JobConf job,
                            Class<? extends DBWritable> inputClass,
                            String inputQuery,
                            String inputCountQuery)
```

It gets the `inputCountQuery` which makes hadoop decide on the number of mappers and how many records per mapper to process.

Also read the *Limitations of the InputFormat* section [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/03/database-access-with-hadoop/).